# Real-time Traffic on Google Maps on Android

Tags: online-resources, netherlands, maps, mobile-apps

On Friday 9:30 AM I would like to be able to evaluate this route on my Android phone via Google Maps to determine if this route is optimal:

[image]

This is a screenshot form my PC, so I do not expect it to be quite the same on my phone.  What symbols and other cues do I need to pay attention to make a good decision as to which route should be taken.  I understand there is construction on the A1 and can halt traffic.

Alternative route 2:

[image]

Alternative route 3:

[image]

Comment: Why not use Waze (you can use it's 'routes' function to see a couple of route options if you want)?

Comment: [There's an app for that.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze)

Comment: PSA: Waze is owned by Google, and it has some benefits - for example, accident data from Waze is available directly in Google Maps.

Comment: Are you asking about Google's mobile App or webapp? I've retagged your question but added the tags covering both possibilities.

Answer (score 9):

> This is a screenshot form my PC, so I do not expect it to be quite the same on my phone

Did you try? On my phone, I get this with the Google maps app,  which *is* quite the same:

[image]

You can select one of the routes by tapping the estimated time labels.

Right now (Wednesday, 8am) there's slow traffic near the airport, but it still takes 30min for 30km, which is not that bad. Google also does not suggest an alternative around that little jam.

The only advantage of the desktop version is that you can give a time, an it it shows how long the trip should have been when in the past, or a prediction when in the future, calculated from collected traffic information. I didn't find that in the app.

Your third route was done by dragging the generated route by mouse, i.e. adding intermediate stops. The app provides this function, too. You can't drag the route, you have to add a stop and can select it from the map.

My personal experience is that Google route planning is really good since it knows the traffic status much more precisely than any other device or service, due to the information it gets from all the Android phones on the streets.

(not really an answer, but the Screenshot doesn't fit into a comment)

Comment: I do not use the google map app but use the same trick on several different satnavs. Enter a location on your prefered route, either as waypoint or as temporary destination and adjust while traveling.